# How to use latest Java version using Maven in Spring application?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am working on `Spring MVC mavenized` based application. This application was using the Java 1.6 although I have installed only Java 8 on my machine. How can we make maven configurations to use the latest java version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `pom.xml`, defined this maven.compiler.source properties to tell Maven to use `Java 8` to compile the project.

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Another Approach-2

```
Compiler Plugin
Alternative, configure the plugin directly.

pom.xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help, In my case it worked. Also along with adding `<java.version>` property I also `Eclipse->Properties->Project Facets->Convert to faceted form`(if not converted) then change java version to 1.8 in drop-down. Change Workspace default JRE to Jdk 1.8 in Java build path settings.

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.stackoverflow.MyClass</start-class>
    </properties>
```

Also set to compiler setting in Eclipse `Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler` to use JDK 1.8.